# CMPedometer not providing step updates after changing BundleID

Tags: ios, swift, object

I'm creating a simple fitness tracking app and I'm at the user testing stage. I changed the BundleID and uploaded the app to iTunesConnect and today I started testing with TestFlight. The first feedback I got was, that no step data was available. I checked and, when trying to get steps data, i get error 105, which means, that the app doesn't have permission to access Motion Data. The problem is, that no confirmation prompt appears and the application doesn't show up in Settings, so that the user can manually set the permission.

After hours of digging through the code, I figured, that if I set the project's BundleID to the old string, the problem disappears - I get the prompt to allow access to Motion Data and receive updates. Unfortunately, I can't change the BundleID in iTunesConnect, since the app has already been distributed to testers. Is there a way to fix the issue without creating a new app?

Comment: I strongly suspect that quickest fix for this will be to change your bundle ID back to what it was and then redistribute the app.

Comment: But then I'd have to create a new app in iTunesConnect, wait for beta test review and resend the invitations, right?

Comment: I guess so, but then that's what beta tests are for right? Shouldn't take much more time than uploading a new version for any other bug fix. At least app review times are nice and quick now. :-)